# why does parent padding not apply to child div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The problem I am having is that a child div is not being affected by its parent's padding. The problem only seems to be in Firefox. It works perfectly in Chrome. The child div just overlaps the parent's padding regardless of how much padding is applied.

The child div is being dynamically instantiated. The parent div is coded in the HTML file. The child div's are inserted into `chat-message-box`

HTML:

```
<div id='chat-messages'>
    <div class='chat-message-box'>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.user-msg-me
{
    float: left;
    min-width: 100px;
    margin: 10px 80px 0 5px;
    padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px;
}

.user-msg-me-continued
{
    float: left;
    min-width: 100px;
    margin: 1px 80px 0 5px;
    padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px;
}
.chat-message-box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #2bda9e;
}
```

Inserted HTML:

```
<div class="user-msg-general">
    <span class="user-msg-me-continued me">
        my message is here
    </span>
</div>
```

Inserted with JQuery:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'php/submitMsg.php',
        data: {'msg': msg},
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(success, data){
            $('.chat-message-box').append(success['html']);
            $('.me').last().text(success['message']);
        },
        error: function(error, data){
            $('.chat-message-box').append(error);
        }
    });
```

[image: Between the red is the issue I am having]

The annoying thing is that, as previously stated, it works in Chrome but does not work in Firefox. I have tried going through the css with -moz prefixes but that doesn't seem to work. I am probably doing something quite stupid with the insertion of the text.

Thanks in advance

Comment: best thing in this cases is creating a fiddle to reproduce the problem

Comment: So where is `.chat-message-box` ?

Comment: This [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/2k2s680f/) appears the same in both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: I think the issue is because it is being dynamically instantiated. It doesn't work when dynamically inserted